# WPF - how to update textbox with currently selecteditem in listview? Using MVVM!

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I'd be grateful if someone could give me some pointers on a very annoying problem I'm having - I'm going crazy trying to make this work as I'm sure there must be a simple solution but I can't see it!

As a result of the very helpful answers to my previous question posted on here, I'm attempting to use the MVVM approach in WPF.

I've got a listview in one page that binds to an ObservableCollection in the viewmodel & the listview's selected item is bound to a property called SelectedEntity in the viewmodel:

```
<Listview Name="listview" ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

In a different page I have a textbox bound to the Name property of SelectedEntity in the viewmodel:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedEntity.Name}" />
```

The code in the viewmodel is:

```
Private Entity selectedEntity;
Public Entity SelectedEntity 
{ 
   get
   {
       return selectedEntity;
   }
   set
   {
       if (selectedEntity != value)
       {
           selectedEntity = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEntity"); 
       }
   }
```

RaisePropertyChanged is a method that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

What I want to do is have the textblock update when the currently selected item in the listview changes but it just won't? Am I missing something really obvious?

Thanks very much for any guidance you can give me!

Comment: When you say `In a different page I have a textbox`, do they both share a same instance of `ViewModel` object? Because your code looks good enough to work. With current information it is hard to find what problem may be.

Comment: Are you using the same ViewModel in both pages or passing a new instance of the ViewModel to each page?

Comment: Hmm those are good questions! I set the datacontext in both pages to be the viewmodel, so I guess that could mean that they're referencing different instances of the viewmodel, hence why the listview updating a property doesn't flag a change in the textbox. I don't know how to set a common datacontext for both pages to reference, but will investigate & let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using the MVVM Light Toolkit and have uploaded it [here](http://cid-136dba83ff6950a3.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Code%20Samples/SelectedItemMVVM.zip)

It works because the ViewModelLocator holds a static reference to the ViewModel

Comment: Thanks so much for posting the code, it's really helpful to see an example that works! I've created a static reference in mine & the listview references it fine, but I'm having trouble getting the textblock to display anything. I'll sit down when I've got some more time & go through it carefully though, as there's probably something small missing that's breaking the whole thing! Thanks again for taking the time to solve this, it's a huge help.

Comment: Finally managed to get it working, I'd written some additional code to test out different ways of making it work & managed to leave in a reference to another data context which was confusing it. I've used your example to generate a static reference to the viewmodel now though & it works perfectly. Many thanks again!